# Do I need CALS if only using Windows Server 2019 as a Hypervisor and non Windows Server services?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019, rds, cal

Here is the situation:

- Windows Server 2019 Host running Hyper-V with 1 Windows Server 2019
  vm and 1 linux vm.
- There will be no active directory, there is no domain, one local admin on the Windows
  Host machine.
- Multiple people will very rarely be accessing the host server and logging in
  over RDP to the local admin account for administration purposes.
- Multiple people will very rarely be logging into the windows server vm to run applications used for managing the linux vm, both also will only have 1 local admin account.
- Many devices will be accessing a web server hosted on the linux vm.

Do I need RDS CALS?
Do I need windows server CALS?

Comment: Licensing questions are off topic here. Time to be a little professional and read the licensing guidelines you signed up for.